# C# DbContext Connection Type and Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a WinForm application developed on one laptop connected to an SQL server on the same laptop.

I have a new laptop and have created a docker setup for an SQL server. I am looking to change the code base to use the new SQL server.

The new server is using SQL Server auth with username and password on the new laptop. The old laptop is using windows authentication on a windows installed setup. I have migrated a copy of the entire DB into my dockerised instance of the sql server.

The application has the connection settings in the app config and naturally this is for windows authentication.

My app.config is comitted to my github repository. I do not want to store the sql user/password in the app.settings, but instead I would like to get these from env variables I set on the machine.

I would also like to know how to change the format of the connection string in app.config so it works with sql server authentication.

Or maybe now I have explained what I am trying to do, there might be a better way?

My current connection strings are

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Blah.Properties.Settings.BlahConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=W.....R....;
        Initial Catalog=Blah;
        Integrated Security=True;
        Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
        TrustServerCertificate=False" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>


[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Blah")]
public partial class BlahDBDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
```

I searched all code for 'AddDbContextFactory' and 'GetConnectionString'

```
    public BlahDBDataContext() :
 base(global::Blah.Properties.Settings.Default.BlahConnectionString, mappingSource) 
{ 
    OnCreated(); 
}


[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=PCNAME;Initial Catalog=Blah;Integrated Security=True" + ";Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")] 
public string BlahConnectionString 
{ 
    get { return ((string)(this["BlahConnectionString"])); 
}
```

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ will show you the difference between "Standard Security" a.k.a. SQLServer username/password and "Trusted Connection" a.k.a. Windows auth. Basically, set "Integrated Security" false and add "User ID" and "Password"

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard that solves one aspect, very much appreciated.

Comment: *I do not want to store the sql user/password in the app.settings, but instead I would like to get these from env variables* - no problem, but show us how the DbContext comes to know the conn str right now so we can advise you how to change that so it picks up the env vars

Comment: I have the settings in app.config mentioned above, so assume you want me to state how I added the dbcontext with those settings. I just added a connection using VS user interface to select the server/DB it then added the settings to app.settings files. Is that what you are asking? thanks

Comment: The line of code that maybe looks like `AddDbContextFactory<YourContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnection"), o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery))` - something somewhere in your program pulls the connection string out of config and sends it into the context, or the thing that makes the contexts. Show us that part. Ctrl-F your whole project for "ConnectionString" if you aren't sure

Comment: Thanks for the direction. difficult to find like you suggest with search all.
However I can see the DB Context has this
 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Blah")]
 public partial class BlahDBDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext

I searched all code for 'AddDbContextFactory' and 'GetConnectionString'

Comment: public BlahDBDataContext() : 
    base(global::Blah.Properties.Settings.Default.BlahConnectionString, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

Comment: In Settings.Designer.cs I can see this: 
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=PCNAME;Initial Catalog=Blah;Integrated Security=True" +
            ";Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")]
        public string BlahConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["BlahConnectionString"]));
            }

Comment: There is also in addition to App.Config and file called Settings.settings with some related connection items in it.

Comment: Please make edits to the question rather than dumping unformatted code into comments. Code in comments should ideally be limited to single line suggestions surrounded by single backticks like this: `code here\`

Comment: @CaiusJard yes your correct, question has been updated. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database context class is generated code inheriting as far as I can tell on System.Data.Linq.DataContext, as shown by this code from my application.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Blah")]
public partial class BlahDBDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
```

The *BlahDBDataContext* class provides a number of constructors. Please check for yourself for a fuller list.

For my purposes the constructor I needed was

```
public BlahDBDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
    base(connection, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

This requires the construction of a *System.Data.IDbConnection* object to hold/manage the connection details.

Therefore in my case all I needed to do was construct the connection string, for example.

```
string userName = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_USERNAME");
string password = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_PASSWORD");
string server = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_SERVER");
string database = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_DATABASE");
connectionString = $@"Data Source={server};Initial Catalog={database};Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;User ID={userName};Password={password};";
```

and then all thats needed is

new BlahDBDataContext(
new SqlConnection(
Program.GetDatabaseConnectionString()))

Where *Program.GetDatabaseConnectionString()* is.

```
    public static string GetDatabaseConnectionString()
    {
        if (connectionString is null)
        {
            string userName = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_USERNAME");
            string password = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_PASSWORD");
            string server = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_SERVER");
            string database = EnvironmentVariables.GetValue("BLAH_DATABASE");
            connectionString = $@"Data Source={server};Initial Catalog={database};Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;User ID={userName};Password={password};";
        }
        return connectionString;
    }
```

From a SOLID principles and clean coding perspective this is requires refactoring, and will be cleaned up now I have working code.